# ASP.NET MVC role is trying to use SQL Server Express not the SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, microsoft.identity.web

I have the following in my web.config file

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="DefaultConnection" 
             connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-6HOPM3U;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;" 
             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I am able to do everything I need to do until I added role-based authentication and added this in my `_Layout.cshtml` file

```
@if(User.IsInRole("Admin"))
{
   <li>@Html.ActionLink("Admin Menu","Index","Main",new{ area = "Admin"},null)</li>
}
```

At which time an error gets thrown that says

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> SQLExpress database file auto-creation error:
>
> The connection string specifies a local SQL Server Express instance using a database location within the application's App_Data directory. The provider attempted to automatically create the application services database because the provider determined that the database does not exist. The following configuration requirements are necessary to successfully check for existence of the application services database and automatically create the application services database:
>
> If the application is running on either Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008R2, special configuration steps are necessary to enable automatic creation of the provider database. Additional information is available at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=160102. If the application's App_Data directory does not already exist, the web server account must have read and write access to the application's directory. This is necessary because the web server account will automatically create the App_Data directory if it does not already exist.
> If the application's App_Data directory already exists, the web server account only requires read and write access to the application's App_Data directory. This is necessary because the web server account will attempt to verify that the SQL Server Express database already exists within the application's App_Data directory. Revoking read access on the App_Data directory from the web server account will prevent the provider from correctly determining if the SQL Server Express database already exists. This will cause an error when the provider attempts to create a duplicate of an already existing database. Write access is required because the web server account's credentials are used when creating the new database.
> SQL Server Express must be installed on the machine.
> The process identity for the web server account must have a local user profile. See the readme document for details on how to create a local user profile for both machine and domain accounts.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)]
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager) +947
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +6050103

System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +38

> System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +531
>
> System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +156
>
> System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +22
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +92   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +219
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +101
> System.Web.Management.SqlServices.GetSqlConnection(String server, String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String connectionString) +78
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to SQL Server database.]
>
> System.Web.Management.SqlServices.GetSqlConnection(String server, String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String connectionString) +131
> System.Web.Management.SqlServices.SetupApplicationServices(String server, String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String connectionString, String database, String dbFileName, SqlFeatures features, Boolean install) +92
> System.Web.Management.SqlServices.Install(String database, String dbFileName, String connectionString) +30
> System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.CreateMdfFile(String fullFileName, String dataDir, String connectionString) +410

When I remove the lines

```
if(User.IsInRole("Admin"))
{

}
```

it works but now I don't have role based access working.

I am not using SQL Server Express. What do I need to change so that the role based part of identity uses the database in my connection string?

Comment: Why do you need both SQL Server and SQL Server Express? Just seems like a strange set up to me.

Comment: I am NOT using Sql Server Express!!!  That is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by adding the following

Added to Web.config

```
     //to appsettings section
<add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false"/>
<add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false"/>

 //to systemweb section
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="Account/Login" />
</authentication>
<roleManager defaultProvider="userRoleProvider" enabled="true">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="userRoleProvider" type="MyNamespace.Models.UserRoleProvider" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

added this class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace MyNamespace.Models
{
    public class UserRoleProvider:RoleProvider
    {
        public override string ApplicationName
        {
            get
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
            set
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

        }

        public override void AddUsersToRoles(string[] usernames, string[] roleNames)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void CreateRole(string roleName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool DeleteRole(string roleName, 
                 bool throwOnPopulatedRole)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override string[] FindUsersInRole(string roleName, 
                 string usernameToMatch)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override string[] GetAllRoles()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string Id)
        {
            using (SqlConnection oConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand oCmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        oCmd.CommandText = "ListUserRoles";
                        oCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        oCmd.Parameters.Add("@UserId", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Id;
                        oCmd.Connection = oConn;
                        oConn.Open();
                        using (SqlDataReader rdr = oCmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            List<RoleName> roleList = new List<RoleName>();
                            while (rdr.Read())
                            {
                                RoleName role = new RoleName
                                {
                                    Name = rdr[1].ToString()
                                };
                                roleList.Add(role);
                            }
                            string[] userRoles = roleList.Select(x=> x.ToString()).ToArray();
                            return userRoles;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Errors.ErrorOccured(ex, "Id = " + Id);
                        return null;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        oCmd.Dispose();
                        oConn.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public override string[] GetUsersInRole(string roleName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool IsUserInRole(string username, string roleName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void RemoveUsersFromRoles(string[] usernames, string[] roleNames)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
       
        public override bool RoleExists(string roleName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }  
    }
}
```

Now it works

Answer (score -2):

The error you are experiencing indicates that there is a problem establishing a connection with SQL Server. If you believe it is correct, please write so I can provide different solutions.

Comment: The error says it cannot connect to Sql Server Express.   I am not using Sql Server Express.   I never use Sql Server Express.   That is what is confusing me.   My connection string points to the Sql Server 2014 database.   Except for the built in Identity code checking for the role, everything else works.   Just that part of it is looking for Sql Server Express for some reason.

Comment: I should mention that all crud operations work.  It is only the part of the Identity that looks at the role that isn't working